# Keybinding overview for SublimeText 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I think the SublimeText 2 editor has a lot of potential, but I'm struggling to learn the keyboard shortcuts, because unlike Vim it doesn't have comprehensive documentation, or a command to show you what each key combination is bound to.

It's frustrating going through the .sublime-keymap files and find that 4 different packages all rebind ctrl+t for their own purposes.

So, is there a way to view all the keybindings in an organised way: by key, by package, by command - with descriptions?

Currently my hack is a bash function that shows me all the keymap lines that mention a certain key.  For example, *sublime_keys '+t'* finds me all the bindings that use the letter "t"

```
function sublime_keys {
    find ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages \( -name 'Default (Linux).sublime-keymap' -or -name 'Default.sublime-keymap' \) -print0 | xargs --null ack-grep -C1 "\".*$*"
}
```

I've tried [KeymapManager](https://github.com/welefen/KeymapManager) but it is very limited - only shows bindings from some of the top-level non-default packages without descriptions or package context.  I suppose I could take time to improve on it.

Is there a package that does this better?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a package called KeyCue on OSX. I find it very helpful because I have the same difficulty in remembering all the keystrokes.
http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/
On the Mac, when you press and hold the "Command" key for 1 sec, a pop up window will appear and show you all the keystroke for Sublime Text 2, and all other software also. I think it scans through all the menu and show you the keystrokes.
You can also add custom keystrokes. I have added for zencoding and color picker as the keystrokes are from installed package and KeyCue cannot pick those up automatically.
The package is not free (Euro20). Well worth the price as I use it frequently and saves me lots of time.

Comment: Sounds ok for Mac.  Besides being on Linux, I'm interested in viewing the plugin keys as well, and keys that are not represented in the menus, and which keybindings are being overridden by later packages.